# Angular2 Router - conditionally hide links

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a way to conditionally hide a router-link in Angular2?

For example, I have the following code;

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['RegisterUser']">Register User</a></li>
```

I want to hide the link when the user is logged in.

On my component, I use the `@CanActivate` decorator to determine if the route can be activated, but this doesn't hide the link itself.

```
@CanActivate(() => hasValidToken())
```

I *could* use the `*ngIf` structural directive with the `hasValidToken()` method (which returns a boolean) but this seems heavy handed and a bit dirty.

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['RegisterUser']" *ngIf="!hasValidToken()">Register User</a></li>
```

Is there a cleaner way to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I did it, which makes it easier if you ever want to add more routes in the future is create a service with an observable that watches for a loggedIn event.

Then I just use ngOnChanges and when someone logs in, I append the other menu items to my menu and do an *ngFor loop over my [routerLink]'s.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  template: `<li *ngFor="#prop in myProps><a [routerLink]="[prop]">Register User</a></li>`
})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() LoggedIn: any;
  constructor(){
    myProps = ['About_Me', 'Not_Logged_In_Menu_Item'];
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    myProps.push(changes['LoggedIn'].currentValue);
    console.log('ngOnChanges - myProps = ' + changes['myProps'].currentValue);
  }
}
```

The only reason I would do it this way though is if you feel down the line you will have to change additional menu items for logged in users.  This was for an Auth and Auth application, where some users had more accesses than other users.

Comment: @MorganG I hope my changes are correct. Please check. (`myProp` <-> `myProps`)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer they are, I was just in the process of fixing those 2 errors, I appreciate it, you are fast!

Comment: @MorganG Whilst this is a good solution, I hope the Angular team build something in properly.  The `RouterLink` directive should accept a `boolean` value as well which basically does what your snippet does.  IMO.

Comment: @MorganG or it should just be smart enough to know that if `@CanActivate` returns false, remove the link from the DOM.  That would be my preferred solution.

Comment: @JonPreece yeah there are a few weirdnesses with how it approaches some of the problems.  I think part of it is, it's still in beta and there are going to be quite a few changes in the future.  Also `@CanActivate` might have some weird "features", I haven't delved into many of them.  But I see questions about it asked all the time.  Might have to look through the source code one of these days.